# Firebase Database giving inconsistent data

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I have a flutter app which is connected to firebase realtime database. I am getting inconsistent values from snapshot, everytime I am trying to retrieve data. Below is what my database looks like:
[image: database picture]

Below is the flutter code, I am using to get all the users in a specific id:

```
new FutureBuilder(
  future: db.child("Users").orderByChild("_id").equalTo("$userId").once(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData){
      final values = snapshot.data!.value;
      print("values: "+values.toString());
      return Text("userName: " + values.toString());
    }
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
  ),
```

The values print statement gives the below result:

```
I/flutter (16745): values: [{phone: +880 (834) 473-3132, name: Luna Bray, _id: 615ec4d64259ae531dec9fcc}]
I/flutter (16745): values: {4: {phone: +880 (881) 491-2540, name: Sondra Paul, _id: 615ec4d6ee0c6d92626c1d55}}
I/flutter (16745): values: {3: {phone: +880 (973) 554-2796, name: Susan Walker, _id: 615ec4d60d00b15c0950e860}}
I/flutter (16745): values: {4: {phone: +880 (881) 491-2540, name: Sondra Paul, _id: 615ec4d6ee0c6d92626c1d55}}
```

As u can see from the print result, only the first print statement is a List and the others are Map. I need either the values from snapshot to be a list or a map. I just need the username of the id that matches the query. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing the result of the array coercion that Firebase's SDKs and REST API perform when they encounter sequential, numeric keys.

The best/most common solution is to not use sequential, numeric keys, but instead use Firebase's built-in `push()` operation to generate the keys for you. For many more reasons on why this is idiomatic, see this blog post: [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

If that is not an option for you, prefix the sequential, numeric keys with a short string, such as "key0", "key1", etc. This ensures that the SDK can't convert it to an array, and gives you a consistent map.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think currently we cannot edit the keys from firebase console and I had to import a user.json file. Firebase import named the keys like 0, 1, 2.

Comment: That's because you imported an array (so the same thing as when you read the keys, but then in reverse). But if you want to be able to query the results in the database as you're trying to, you will have to ensure the keys don't get coerced into array indices as I've described.

Comment: Hey @KamrulHasanJony. Any update here?

Comment: I just changed my json data using key0, key1 as you suggested. It worked after that